# C# ThreadPool Priorization

Tags: c#, .net, performance, runtime, threadpool

We have a main thread that scedules several tasks of different priorities.

Let us say, there would be **100 tasks** that perform an **operation on some data**. This operations can happen in the background and currenlty we **do not care about how long they take to complete**.

Now the main thread **requires some data** that one of the tasks is processing and calls **await on the task handle**.

**Question 1:** Will the task that is awaited be prioritized over the other workload tasks?

**Question 2:** Is there a way to control the order of executed tasks after it has been kicked of in the queue?

**Question 2:** I know that the Unity Job System is able to do exactly that, but has the .NET Framework an equivalent or alternative solution?

Comment: No, no, you can use custom task scheduler (for example: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2010/04/09/parallelextensionsextras-tour-7-additional-taskschedulers/).

Comment: You could use `TaskScheduler` and have properties such as `Priority, maxConcurrencyLevel`